# Removing duplicate entries?

Tags: python

I need to compare values from different rows. Each row is a dictionary, and I need to compare the values in adjacent rows for the key 'flag'. How would I do this? Simply saying:

```
for row in range(1,len(myjson))::
      if row['flag'] == (row-1)['flag']:
             print yes
```

returns a TypeError: `'int' object is not subscriptable`

Even though range returns a list of ints...

---

RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:

List of rows is a list of dictionaries.  Originally, I import a tab-delimited file and read it in using the csv.dict module such that it is a list of dictionaries with the keys corresponding to the variable names.

Code: (where myjson is a list of dictionaries)

```
for row in myjson:
    print row
```

Output:

```
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 0, 'name': 'Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.', 'email': ''}
{'website': 'www.got.com', 'phone': '111-222-3333', 'flag': 1, 'name': 'Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP', 'email': 'cersei@got.com'}
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 2, 'name': 'Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.', 'email': ''}
{'website': 'www.daManWithThePlan.com', 'phone': '000-000-1111', 'flag': 3, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': 'dman123@gmail.com'}
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 3, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': ''}
{'website': 'www.daManWithThePlan.com', 'phone': '111-222-333', 'flag': 3, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': 'dman123@gmail.com'}
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 4, 'name': 'D G Bamf M.S.', 'email': ''}
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 5, 'name': 'Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.', 'email': ''}
```

Also:

```
type(myjson)

<type 'list'>
```

Comment: what is the data type of the list_of_rows?

Comment: If you are getting that `TypeError`, it's unlikely that `list_of_rows` contains dictionaries.

Comment: What line is the `TypeError` raising from?  I bet it's `(row-1)['flag']`, which means that `row` is an `int` (the calculation succeeds, but the `int` is not subscriptable), and thus `list_of_rows` is an iterable of `ints`.

Comment: Error is indeed occurring on that line.

Comment: .. your code loops over `list_of_rows`, but you show instead `myjson`, so that's not really evidence that you're really looping over a list of dictionaries.  Inside your `for row in list_of_rows:` loop, add `print repr(row), type(row)`, and you'll probably see that @sr2222 is right.  In any case, `row-1` wouldn't work even if `row` *were* a dictionary.

Comment: I know that it wouldn't work, but articulated that poorly in the question. I think I just needed to find out the enumerate function would give me an index / row. I also know that myjson is a list of dicts.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure this isn't the actual code that is throwing this error.  If `row` were a dictionary, the `TypeError` would be for unsupported operand for the `-`.  If it were an `int`, you'd get the `TypeError` you are seeing when it first tries to index in to `row` for the first operand in the `if` statement.

Comment: See my update to the code.

Comment: Right, so `row` is an integer and `row['flag']` throws that exception. `myjson[row]['flag']` is what you were looking for..

Comment: `row` won't be a dictionary now.  You'd have to use `myjson[row]['flag'] == myjson[row-1]['flag']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception indicates that `list_of_rows` is not what you think it is.

To look at other, adjacent rows, provided `list_of_rows` is indeed a list, I'd use `enumerate()` to include the current index and then use that index to load next and previous rows:

```
for i, row in enumerate(list_of_rows):
    previous = list_of_rows[i - 1] if i else None
    next = list_of_rows[i + 1] if i + 1 < len(list_of_rows) else None
```

Comment: How do I deal with the first row if I'm looking behind?

Comment: that is up to you; skip the first row if you don't have a previous row if you want to.

Comment: I'm confused, given that when I print 'row' it gives me a list of numbers, why this would not work.  Note that in my amended code in the question, my for loop goes through this: range(1,len(myjson))

Comment: You attempted to use `row` (an index, taken from the `range()`) as a dictionary with `row['flag']`. Instead, you probably meant to use `row` as an index into `list_of_rows`.

Answer (score 2):

For comparing adjacent items you can use `zip`:

**Example:**

```
>>> lis = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7]
for x,y in zip(lis, lis[1:]):
     if x == y :
        print x,y,'are equal'
...         
1 1 are equal
4 4 are equal
7 7 are equal
```

For your list of dictionaries, you can do something like :

```
from itertools import izip
it1 = iter(list_of_dicts)
it2 = iter(list_of_dicts)
next(it2)
for x,y in izip(it1, it2):
      if x['flag'] == y['flag']
             print yes
```

**Update:**

For more than 2 adjacent items you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> lis =  [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4]
for k,group in groupby(lis):
     print list(group)

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2]
[3]
[4]
```

For your code it would be :

```
>>> for k, group in groupby(dic, key = lambda x : x['flag']):
...     print list(group)
...     
[{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 0, 'name': 'Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.', 'email': ''}]
[{'website': 'www.got.com', 'phone': '111-222-3333', 'flag': 1, 'name': 'Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP', 'email': 'cersei@got.com'}]
[{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 2, 'name': 'Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.', 'email': ''}]
[{'website': 'www.daManWithThePlan.com', 'phone': '000-000-1111', 'flag': 3, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': 'dman123@gmail.com'}, {'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 3, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': ''}, {'website': 'www.daManWithThePlan.com', 'phone': '111-222-333', 'flag': 3, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': 'dman123@gmail.com'}]
[{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 4, 'name': 'D G Bamf M.S.', 'email': ''}]
[{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 5, 'name': 'Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.', 'email': ''}]
```

Comment: This creates a lot of copies of the lists; if the list is large, that could be quite a problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That can be handled by using izip and iterators.

Comment: I'm also concerned what happens if I have more than 2 that are the same (ex: [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4])

Comment: @goldisfine you can use `itertools.groupby` for that.

Comment: @goldisfine I've added an example related to `itertools.groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to access list elements in batches:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303279/

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
pre_item = list_of_rows[0]['flag']
for row in list_of_rows[1:]:
      if row['flag'] == pre_item :
             print yes
      pre_item = row['flag']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_rows = [ { 'a': 'foo',
                   'flag': 'bar' },
                 { 'a': 'blo',
                   'flag': 'bar' } ]
for row, successor_row in zip(list_of_rows, list_of_rows[1:]):
    if row['flag'] == successor_row['flag']:
        print "yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. If you need to remove those dicts that have the same value for key "flag", as the title of your post suggests (it is somewhat misleading because your dictionaries are not strictly speaking duplicates), you can simply loop over the whole list of dictionaries, keeping track of flags in a separate list, if an item has a flag which is already in the list of flags simply don't add it, it would look something like:

```
def filterDicts(listOfDicts):
    result = []
    flags = []
    for di in listOfDicts:
        if di["flag"] not in flags:
            result.append(di)
            flags.append(di["flag"])
    return result
```

When called with value of list of dictionaries that you have provided, it returns list with 5 items, each has an unique value of flag.